# Submit N sequential jobs in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I want to train a neural network on a cluster which uses SLURM to manage jobs. There is a time limit of 10 hours imposed on each job submitted. Therefore, I need a script that could automatically submit sequential jobs i.e. train from scratch for the first job and reload the checkpoint from the most recent job to continue training for the second job afterwards.

I have written the following script. I would like to know if this is okay or if there is any standard way to handle this in SLURM.

```
#!/bin/bash

Njobs=1000

# Read the configuration variables
# Each training should have a difference config
CONFIG=experiments/model.cfg
source $CONFIG

# Submit first job - no dependencies
j0=$(sbatch run-debug.slurm $CONFIG)
echo "ID of the first job: $j0"

# add first job to the list of jobs
jIDs+=($j0)

# for loop: submit Njobs: where job (i+1) is dependent on job i.
# and job (i+1) (i.e. new_job) resume from the checkpoint of job i
for i in $(seq 0 $Njobs); do
    # Submit job (i+1) with dependency ('afterok:') on job i
    RESUME_CHECKPOINT=$OUTPUTPATH/$EXPNAME/${jIDs[$i - 1 ]}/checkpoint.pkl
    new_job=$(sbatch  --dependency=afterok:${jIDs[$i - 1 ]} run-debug.slurm $CONFIG $RESUME_CHECKPOINT)
    echo "Submitted job $new_job that will be executed once job ${jIDs[$i - 1 ]} has completed with success."
    echo "This task will resume training from $RESUME_CHECKPOINT."
    jIDs+=($new_job)
    echo "List of jobs that have been submitted: $jIDs"
done
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!